# Change SVG color based on current background

Tags: javascript, css, svg

How to change svg color (fill) based on current background color?

We know this works for text: https://css-tricks.com/reverse-text-color-mix-blend-mode/

So is it posible to do it for svg fill somehow?

Comment: mix-blend-mode works for svg too: https://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/NqRxJZ

Comment: "current background color" - background color of what?

Comment: Try to make it transparent like `<svg style="background-color: transparent;" ...`

Comment: I would like to know what you have in mind. There are so many possibilities. Please add a basic example (a working example) of what you want to achieve.