# SVG & Angular2+ Change color of element based on background

Tags: angular, typescript, svg

I have a `text` element after two `rect` elements in an `svg` element.

```
<svg id="floor-plan" width="300" height="100">
<rect width="300" height="100"fill="white"/>
<rect width="50" height="50" fill="green"/>
<text x="10" y="10"dy="1.5em" fill="white">dfdklsfjsadgkldsjfglkdsjfklögj</text>
```

The `rect` in the `rect` is smaller than the `text` element.
I want to change the color of the `text` element if the `text` is outside of the first `rect` element and in front of the green `rect`.

How can I do that?

Thanks for the effort.

The question is asked in a kind of similar way but with no proper code example: [Change SVG color based on current background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55075387/change-svg-color-based-on-current-background)

Comment: If you found a solution, that's great but you should write an answer rather than editing the answer into the question.

Answer (score 0):

Please add some class and change css file like this:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 300 80" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <style>
    .small { font: italic 13px sans-serif; }
    .heavy { font: bold 30px sans-serif; }

    /* Обратите внимание, что цвет текста задается с помощью        *
     * fill свойства, а свойство color используется только для HTML */
    .Rrrrr { font: italic 40px serif; fill: red; }
  </style>

  <text x="20" y="35" class="small">Мой</text>
  <text x="60" y="35" class="heavy">кот</text>
  <text x="60" y="55" class="small">очень</text>
  <text x="100" y="55" class="Rrrrr">Сердит!</text>
</svg>
```

Also you can check it here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/SVG/%D0%AD%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82/%3Ctext%3E

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode also work in SVG.

```
text {
   mix-blend-mode: difference;
}
```